# Swift 4 iMessage sending message: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.messages.messagesapp-error error 9.)

Tags: swift, xcode, imessage

When sending a message, it throws an error with a random code. No description or anything. Here is my code:

```
       if #available(iOSApplicationExtension 11.0, *) {
            conversation?.send(message, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        } else {
            conversation?.insert(message, completionHandler: { (error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription)
                }
            })
        }
```

Error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.messages.messagesapp-error error 9.)

It works fine when I use the insert function. Really bugging me haha, get it? Bug-ing... no? ok.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error code on Apple's beta documentation:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages/msmessageerrorcode/2909031-sendwithoutrecentinteraction
Apparently the app requires user interaction before sending (which my app had,) but for some reason it still triggers it.

Comment: I noticed this as well. I filed a radar just in case, but it should probably be fixed soon.